# Deserialization exception handling

Tags: c#, xml, exception, deserialization

If I read this xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <FontPath>sciezka</FontPath>
    <CodingCP852v2>44</CodingCP852v2>
    <LedText>Napismoj</LedText>
 </Settings>
```

deserialization will show in inner exception:

```
{"The string '44' is not a valid Boolean value."}
```

Now I would like to read from exception object name of field wchich caused exception  (in this example I should get "Coding"). How to do that?

```
[Serializable]
public class Settings
{
    public string FontPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool Coding
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

try
{
     using (FileStream s = File.OpenRead(fileName))
     {
           XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
                return (Settings)xs.Deserialize(s);
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     return new Settings();
}
```

Comment: I have to ask why is Coding a Boolean in the first place?

Comment: Have you considered just displaying the exception text? It strikes me that the only reason you would want to allow an error like this is because you have user editable xml input. You may as well expose them to the error as they are familiar with xml. Throw in the line and column numbers and they have all the information they need to identify the erroneous value.

Comment: This would be a mistake, there are many possible other mishaps in an XML file beyond a bad value for an element.  Trying to produce useful info from a corrupted file is dangerous, it is just as likely that your "useful info" is going to be corrupt as well.  Sending the user off on a wild goose chase.  You already get a good inner exception that tells the user *exactly* where to look in the file for the corruption, don't help.

Answer (score 0):

The XmlSerializer will *always* throw and `InvalidOperationException`. The inner exception in your case will be a `System.Xml.XmlException`

The documentation for this exception shows you the properties that are likely to be avaliable. None of them are the name of the erroneous node. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlexception.aspx

It appears that the only way to get the name is to manually parse the document using an `XmlReader` and check the types yourself. This will give you very fine grained control over the type mapping and validation if you omit a schema. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx